# Eclipse Tomcat remote debugging: are the sources from eclipse cached somewhere?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, remote-debugging

while debugging a tomcat 6, we discovered that two classes are different between the deployment in Tomcat and in Eclipse. The deployment in Tomcat creates a NullPOinterException, the Eclipse sources don't. The thing is, if we startup Tomcat with `startup.sh` it produces the error...every time! If we startup with `catalina jpda start`, connect Eclipse to it, it produces the error AS LONG as we don't change the value of a certain property, that causes this error. After we changed this value, the error is gone even if we delete the deployment folder and work directory and start again in debug mode. No Exception. BUT, if we restart again with `startup.sh` the error appears again.

So, my question is, does Tomcat or Eclipse cache/store the sources from Eclipse somewhere for usage with the remote debugger?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse (and I believe others like IDEA and Netbeans) replace the running code on the server "on save" when you debug the application. This means that when changing a class in Eclipse, save it and it will change it on the server. Also known as code replace. I also believe that tomcat logs the change in catalina.out
However, when you restart the server, it gets the class that has been deployed earlier so you get the class before the changes in Eclipse.

Comment: Okay! Need to check the catalina.out for this. But how does this explain, that if I have started with `startup.sh` (including the error) and then restart again with `catalina jpda start` the error is again gone? Remember, the very first time I started in debug mode the error was there until I changed this property.

Comment: I believe tomcat has a work directory beside the webapp. The updated class under debug are "pushed" there but on a restart startup.sh it reads from the webapp but debug still merge with the work directory.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot verify this. If I delete al subfolders in the work directory and also delete the folders in webapps, it's still working correctly when started in debug mode whereas it's not working in normal startup. This really annoys me! :-)